# unknown error when i try to verify my google account

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

I have a Samsung 7 and I factory reset it for a family member to use now i have it back and they reset it for m now i cant pass the verification page?

I sign in with password and it comes up with unknown error and takes me back to sign in my gmail emailed me that a Samsung tried signing in and I confirm its me but still no access

Help Please

Comment: Does it ask for old account maybe it has factory reset protection, and need to enter old account credentials, and then new

Answer (score 2):

Try to set right date and time on your phone.

**For clarification:**

An authorization is usually done through https requests. Https requests do not pass if the device has an old enough date that does not correspond to the actual date. This usually happens after resetting the device to the factory settings. Therefore the first what needs to do - setup correctly date and time on the device.

Wrong date and time are a typical reason of problems with authentication after factory reset.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I improved my answer.

Comment: How do you set the date and time if you can't get past the verify your accouct page. I have a samsung s6.